# Is the PHP function parse_ini_file() really so dangerous?

Tags: php, security, joomla

A few hosting providers disable the PHP function parse_ini_file().
Any attempt to use it there, will fail with the error "parse_ini_file() has been disabled for security reasons".
This configuration is so common that Joomla, which is one of the most popular CMS, avoids the direct use of parse_ini_file() in favour of dividing the task in two steps:

1. Reading the file content with file_get_contents()
2. Parsing the values with parse_ini_string(), which is strangely allowed, hence it's not considered a security risk (WTF?)

My question is, how using parse_ini_file() **could be considered a security threat**, or how disable the PHP function parse_ini_file() could improve the security?

**Could it be a hoax?**
I mean, maybe someone, somewhere in the past, confused parse_ini_file() with ini_set(), and thought that parse_ini_file() can change the configuration of the PHP environment.
Bloggers could have advised here and there, and naive system administrators could have followed the advices without asking themselves any questions.

Comment: I can't find a sensible reason to disable it. My hint: Ask a hosting provider who does that. ;)

Answer (score 8):

The security risk that that restrictions on `parse_ini_file` attempt to guard against is *reading from an arbitrary file*, not in parsing its contents.

Reading from an arbitrary file can be considered a security threat if you're able to read files that you normally shouldn't access (e.g. the system's password file; or users belonging to another user). Even if the files aren't in an ini format, the results that are returned by `parse_ini_file()` could still be potentially informative.

In PHP <= 5.3.x, `parse_ini_file()` [was restricted](http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.functions.php) when [safe mode](http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php) was enabled. In PHP >= 5.4, safe mode was removed (in favor of requiring *actual* system-level security, rather than the language playing a losing game of whack-a-mole with more and more functionality that could read from arbitrary files in increasingly creative ways).

The recommendation to ban `parse_ini_file()` is an old one, from when safe mode was still a thing. It's no more dangerous than any other PHP function that reads from a file. A hosting provider that's banning `parse_ini_file()` now (especially after leaving `file_get_contents()` open is misguided, operating from old advice that is no longer valid, and was of dubious benefit even when it was valid.

The code in the PHP sources for `parse_ini_file()` essentially boils down to calling the same code as `parse_ini_string`, just with a slightly different initialization pattern (so that the one can read from a file, and the other a string). Otherwise, they're using identical code for actually parsing the ini file and returning results.

Comment: Thanks jbafford, but this does not explain why on the hosts where parse_ini_file() is disabled, file_get_contents() is enabled. If they wanted to prevent file open, they should have disabled file_get_contents() too.

Comment: @Fox Because it's a misguided attempt at security following from a misunderstanding of old advice that is no longer applicable. There is *no good reason* to disable `parse_ini_file()` if you're going to leave `file_get_contents()` open.